# Apply patches to a specific path in Repository

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using **Tortoise-Hg**, and have a **Mercurial** repository

In my Tortoise-Hg Repository Settings, I have two paths for remote repositories; **A** as **parent**, and **B** as **default**. (parent and default are just aliases)

This is the situation;
Have a repository **A** on the network, where many developers clone from. 
Have my cloned repository **B** on the network. I own this repository .
Have the local repository to code my changes in my C drive. The usual stuff...

Once I make my code changes in local, I push those to **B** and if stuff in **B** gets approved than it gets pushed into **A** from my local repository for release.

Now I need to ***push*** ***few*** ***patches*** to **A** because I have non-approved change-sets in local where I already pushed to **B** for review.

I've created patches for multiple change-sets by using Export functionality of Tortoise-Hg Workbench.

Now how do I apply these patches to **A** on the remote path by using a GUI tool or command line? I should not apply to **B** again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assuming wrong about the possibility of applying patches directly to a URL. Now I know that such a thing is not possible. All I had to do was to create another repository of A on my hard drive and import patches of B to there.